# what is wrong with the selector for a valuetype here, objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum
{
    CellTypeTextInput,
    CellTypePicker
}CellType;

@interface TVCellWithProperties : UITableViewCell {


    CellType _cellType;
}

-(void)setCellType:(CellType)newType;
-(CellType)CellType;

@end
```

The Header

```
#import "TVCellWithProperties.h"

@implementation TVCellWithProperties

-(void)setCellType:(CellType)newType
{
    _cellType = newType;
}

-(CellType)CellType
{
    return  _cellType;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I'm doing

```
[cell setCellType:CellTypePicker];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell setCellType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f66c30'

I tried the default accessors first using synthesize, but didn't work so i tried doing things manually and it still can't find the selector. Because it's not seeing the UITableViewCell as TVCellWithProperties. 
What's wrong with my implementation ?

I was doing the following:

```
TVCellWithProperties *cell = (TVCellWithProperties*)[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EditableContent" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = tvCell;
        self.tvCell=nil;
    }
```

The problem was that in the nibfile, the tableviewCell i was loading was of type 'UITableViewCell', so i made it 'TVCellWithProperties'.
and it worked.

Thank you NR4TR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you are sending message to `TVCellWithProperties` instance but not `UITableViewCell` instance? Check initializations inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Thank you for the eye opening.

Comment: The problem was that in the nibfile, the tableviewCell i was loading was of type 'UITableViewCell', so i made it 'TVCellWithProperties'. and it worked.

Thank you NR4TR